# Issues with git when beign trying to upload a repo

Tags: git

I recentlly get back from time work do not let me study, but when I'm trying to upload a repo, pops up:

$ git push -u origin main
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'

$ git config --list
Displays a buch of thinks like:

diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain, filter.lfs, core, pullrebase, username, user mail

I ALREADY ERASED GIT COMPLETELY AND RE-SET IT... DID NOT WORK.
I ASUME GIT KEEPS CREDENTIALS IN PC...
I ALREADY GOT SET MY USER AND MAIL ... DID NOT WORK EITHER.

Comment: Does the branch `main` exist? What does `git branch` output?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+src+refspec+main+does+not+match+any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You told Git to push the `main` branch to the `origin` remote, but you got this error because there is no branch named `main` in that repo. Does this repo have any commits at all? (Can't have a branch without commits.) Are there branches with different names? (`git branch` will list all the ones you have locally; many long-standing repos will have a branch named `master` instead of `main`.)

Comment: Hi there Jim, Thank u' for taking the time to help me out with solving this issue. git config user.name "new name"
git config credential.username "new name"

Comment: This two code lines helped me out with the problem. It was bout' permition from users (my users) I created during my time trying to learn git and github.